# Layout color is changing on touch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a Layout background color set to gray.
in the layout i have 3 edit texts.
when i touch any edittext the layout background color disappears.
and on every other touch on the edit text the color returns and disappears again.

does anyone have a suggestion what could this be?

there is no java, this is only set to be a view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/gray" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:ems="9"
        android:hint="Patient ID"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:ems="6"
        android:hint="First"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:ems="6"
        android:hint="Last"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

it works whent i erase the 
 android:background="#FF000000"
from all edit text layouts.

i need my edit texts to have black background so what should i do?

Comment: If you just need a black background use #000 as your color. The format you are using is #AARRGGBB. I would also check things like styles.xml and themes.xml if you created one. More than once I have made changes there and forgot about them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#a0a0a0"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/test_btn">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:ems="9"
        android:hint="Patient ID"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:ems="6"
        android:hint="First"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:ems="6"
        android:hint="Last"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"/>
</LinearLayout>
```